# Get the ClearCase VOB of an activity, stream or stream location with cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, vob

I'm trying to write a script to get the vob with the help of cleartool.

I have the activity id, the stream name and the stream location as input. From this I need to get the vob.

`cleartool lsvob -short` is pretty much what I need, but I only need the vob of the activity and stream.

`cleartool describe -cview view-location` did also not help.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
`cleartool descr -cact` leads to the following:

```
activity "ActivityID"
created 2014-12-15T13:53:49+01:00 by User
master replica: HES@\vob
owner: dom\owner
group: group
stream: stream@\vob
current view: view name
title: Title
change set versions:
  ...changes
Attributes:
  activity_ok = "yes"
  Delivered = "no"
  Finished = "no"
  Type_Activity = "User"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a cleartool describe from within the view, it should pick up on the "vob of the activity" (meaning the PVob which is an admin vob of the current UCM root-based component vob that the view is accessing)

```
cd /path/to/my/view/vobs/MyVob

cleartool descr -cact
cleartool descr -fmt "%Xn" -cact
```

That should return the name of the currently set activity followed by `@/vobs/ThePVob`.
`ThePVob` is the tag you are looking for: it will be the same for all activities in that stream.

Using [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6), you can limit the output to the fully qualified name of the current activity: activty@\.

Comment: Please replace ct by cleartoolit was a typo. I have edited the answer

Comment: If you are on Windows,  the @\vob is the vob tag you are after

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to just get the vob as a one-line return?
`activity_id@\vob` would even be better

Comment: this is exactly what I needed!
Next time I will directly ask my question correct :)